# What is error "Flag '-' is not valid for 'create project'."?

Tags: android, cordova, ubuntu-10.10

I am trying to compile a PhoneGap project via command

```
droidgap create
```

I constantly receive an error: `Error: Flag '-' is not valid for 'create project'.`.

To be more precise, I do not receive any other errors (like FAILED or similar), but this one only. Also the xxx_android folder does get created in the parent directory.

Can I disregard this message? What does it mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens on Linux systems if the PhoneGap project is located in directories that have spaces in it, like "/home/username/some dir with spaces/".

It seems that PhoneGap does not handle this well.

Comment: `C:\Users\mack\AndroidStudioProjects\tess-two-master\tess-two-master\eyes-two>android update project -target 1 -path C:/User
s/mack/AndroidStudioProjects/tess-two-master/tess-two-master/tess-two
Error: Argument '_the path of tess two_' is not recognized.`
I have no spcaes in between but still i am getting the error, can you please guide me here about the issue. @sandalone